# page does not end up directly under domain

Tags: apache-2.2, ubuntu, tomcat, ubuntu-12.10, tomcat7

I'm trying to set up a java page using Apache and tomcat on a Ubuntu server. The problem I'm having is that the page does not end up under the domain but in a virtual folder on the domain like this.

```
example.com/example/
```

If i enter example.com the page can not be found.
How do i get the page to show up under example.com?

Here is my sites-available config

```
<VirtualHost *:8080>
        ServerName example.com
        DocumentRoot /www/example

        <Directory /www/example/>
                AllowOverride All
                Order allow,deny
                allow from all
        </Directory>

        JkMount /* worker1
</VirtualHost>
```

Here is the workers.properties

```
worker.list=worker1
worker.worker1.type=ajp13
worker.worker1.host=localhost
worker.worker1.port=8009
```

jk.conf

```
# Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one or more
# contributor license agreements.  See the NOTICE file distributed with
# this work for additional information regarding copyright ownership.
# The ASF licenses this file to You under the Apache License, Version 2.0
# (the "License"); you may not use this file except in compliance with
# the License.  You may obtain a copy of the License at
#
#     http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
#
# Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
# distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
# WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
# See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
# limitations under the License.
# Configuration Example for mod_jk
# used in combination with Apache 2.2.x
<IfModule jk_module>
    # We need a workers file exactly once
    # and in the global server
    JkWorkersFile /etc/apache2/workers.properties
    # Our JK error log
    # You can (and should) use rotatelogs here
    JkLogFile /var/log/apache2/mod_jk.log
    # Our JK log level (trace,debug,info,warn,error)
    JkLogLevel info
    # Our JK shared memory file
    JkShmFile /var/log/apache2/jk-runtime-status
    # Define a new log format you can use in any CustomLog in order
    # to add mod_jk specific information to your access log.
    # LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\" \"%{Cookie}i\" \"%{Set-Cookie}o\" %{pid}P %{tid}P %{JK_LB_FIRST_NAME}n %{JK_LB_LAST_NAME}n ACC %{JK_LB_LAST_ACCESSED}n ERR %{JK_LB_LAST_ERRORS}n BSY %{JK_LB_LAST_BUSY}n %{JK_LB_LAST_STATE}n %D" extended_jk
    # This option will reject all requests, which contain an
    # encoded percent sign (%25) or backslash (%5C) in the URL
    # If you are sure, that your webapp doesn't use such
    # URLs, enable the option to prevent double encoding attacks.
    # Since: 1.2.24
    # JkOptions +RejectUnsafeURI
    # After setting JkStripSession to "On", mod_jk will
    # strip all ";jsessionid=..." from request URLs it
    # does *not* forward to a backend.
    # This is useful, if all links in a webapp use
    # URLencoded session IDs and parts of the static
    # content should be delivered directly by Apache.
    # Of course you can also do it with mod_rewrite.
    # Since: 1.2.21
    # JkStripSession On
    # Start a separate thread for internal tasks like
    # idle connection probing, connection pool resizing
    # and load value decay.
    # Run these tasks every JkWatchdogInterval seconds.
    # Since: 1.2.27
    JkWatchdogInterval 60
    # Configure access to jk-status and jk-manager
    # If you want to make this available in a virtual host,
    # either move this block into the virtual host
    # or copy it logically there by including "JkMountCopy On"
    # in the virtual host.
    # Add an appropriate authentication method here!
    <Location /jk-status>
        # Inside Location we can omit the URL in JkMount
        JkMount jk-status
        Order deny,allow
        Deny from all
        Allow from 127.0.0.1
    </Location>
    <Location /jk-manager>
        # Inside Location we can omit the URL in JkMount
        JkMount jk-manager
        Order deny,allow
        Deny from all
        Allow from 127.0.0.1
    </Location>
    # If you want to put all mounts into an external file
    # that gets reloaded automatically after changes
    # (with a default latency of 1 minute),
    # you can define the name of the file here.
    # JkMountFile conf/extra/uriworkermap.properties
    # Example for Mounting a context to the worker "balancer"
    # The URL syntax "a|b" instantiates two mounts at once,
    # the first one is "a", the second one is "ab".
    # JkMount /myapp|/* balancer
    # Example for UnMounting requests for all workers
    # using a simple URL pattern
    # Since: 1.2.26
    # JkUnMount /myapp/static/* *
    # Example for UnMounting requests for a named worker
    # JkUnMount /myapp/images/* balancer
    # Example for UnMounting requests using regexps
    # SetEnvIf REQUEST_URI "\.(htm|html|css|gif|jpg|js)$" no-jk
    # Example for setting a reply timeout depending on the request URL
    # Since: 1.2.27
    # SetEnvIf Request_URI "/transactions/" JK_REPLY_TIMEOUT=600000
    # Example for disabling reply timeouts for certain request URLs
    # Since: 1.2.27
    # SetEnvIf Request_URI "/reports/" JK_REPLY_TIMEOUT=0
    # IMPORTANT: Mounts and virtual hosts
    # If you are using VirtualHost elements, you
    # - can put mounts only used in some virtual host into its VirtualHost element 
    # - can copy all global mounts to it using "JkMountCopy On" inside the VirtualHost
    # - can copy all global mounts to all virtual hosts by putting
    #   "JkMountCopy All" into the global server
    # Since: 1.2.26
</IfModule>
```

server.xml

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<!--
  Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one or more
  contributor license agreements.  See the NOTICE file distributed with
  this work for additional information regarding copyright ownership.
  The ASF licenses this file to You under the Apache License, Version 2.0
  (the "License"); you may not use this file except in compliance with
  the License.  You may obtain a copy of the License at
      http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
  Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
  distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
  WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
  See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
  limitations under the License.
-->
<!-- Note:  A "Server" is not itself a "Container", so you may not
     define subcomponents such as "Valves" at this level.
     Documentation at /docs/config/server.html
 -->
<Server port="8005" shutdown="SHUTDOWN">
  <!-- Security listener. Documentation at /docs/config/listeners.html
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityListener" />
  -->
  <!--APR library loader. Documentation at /docs/apr.html -->
  <!--
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener" SSLEngine="on" />
  -->
  <!--Initialize Jasper prior to webapps are loaded. Documentation at /docs/jasper-howto.html -->
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.JasperListener" />
  <!-- Prevent memory leaks due to use of particular java/javax APIs-->
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.JreMemoryLeakPreventionListener" />
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.mbeans.GlobalResourcesLifecycleListener" />
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.ThreadLocalLeakPreventionListener" />
  <!-- Global JNDI resources
       Documentation at /docs/jndi-resources-howto.html
  -->
  <GlobalNamingResources>
    <!-- Editable user database that can also be used by
         UserDatabaseRealm to authenticate users
    -->
    <Resource name="UserDatabase" auth="Container"
              type="org.apache.catalina.UserDatabase"
              description="User database that can be updated and saved"
              factory="org.apache.catalina.users.MemoryUserDatabaseFactory"
              pathname="conf/tomcat-users.xml" />
  </GlobalNamingResources>
  <!-- A "Service" is a collection of one or more "Connectors" that share
       a single "Container" Note:  A "Service" is not itself a "Container",
       so you may not define subcomponents such as "Valves" at this level.
       Documentation at /docs/config/service.html
   -->
  <Service name="Catalina">
    <!--The connectors can use a shared executor, you can define one or more named thread pools-->
    <!--
    <Executor name="tomcatThreadPool" namePrefix="catalina-exec-"
        maxThreads="150" minSpareThreads="4"/>
    -->
    <!-- A "Connector" represents an endpoint by which requests are received
         and responses are returned. Documentation at :
         Java HTTP Connector: /docs/config/http.html (blocking & non-blocking)
         Java AJP  Connector: /docs/config/ajp.html
         APR (HTTP/AJP) Connector: /docs/apr.html
         Define a non-SSL HTTP/1.1 Connector on port 8080
    -->
    <Connector port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
               connectionTimeout="20000"
               URIEncoding="UTF-8"
               redirectPort="8443" />
    <!-- A "Connector" using the shared thread pool-->
    <!--
    <Connector executor="tomcatThreadPool"
               port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
               connectionTimeout="20000"
               redirectPort="8443" />
    -->
    <!-- Define a SSL HTTP/1.1 Connector on port 8443
         This connector uses the JSSE configuration, when using APR, the
         connector should be using the OpenSSL style configuration
         described in the APR documentation -->
    <!--
    <Connector port="8443" protocol="HTTP/1.1" SSLEnabled="true"
               maxThreads="150" scheme="https" secure="true"
               clientAuth="false" sslProtocol="TLS" />
    -->
    <!-- Define an AJP 1.3 Connector on port 8009 -->
    <Connector port="8009" protocol="AJP/1.3" redirectPort="8443"/>
    <!-- An Engine represents the entry point (within Catalina) that processes
         every request.  The Engine implementation for Tomcat stand alone
         analyzes the HTTP headers included with the request, and passes them
         on to the appropriate Host (virtual host).
         Documentation at /docs/config/engine.html -->
    <!-- You should set jvmRoute to support load-balancing via AJP ie :
    <Engine name="Catalina" defaultHost="localhost" jvmRoute="jvm1">
    -->
    <Engine name="Catalina" defaultHost="localhost">
      <!--For clustering, please take a look at documentation at:
          /docs/cluster-howto.html  (simple how to)
          /docs/config/cluster.html (reference documentation) -->
      <!--
      <Cluster className="org.apache.catalina.ha.tcp.SimpleTcpCluster"/>
      -->
      <!-- Use the LockOutRealm to prevent attempts to guess user passwords
           via a brute-force attack -->
      <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.LockOutRealm">
        <!-- This Realm uses the UserDatabase configured in the global JNDI
             resources under the key "UserDatabase".  Any edits
             that are performed against this UserDatabase are immediately
             available for use by the Realm.  -->
        <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.UserDatabaseRealm"
               resourceName="UserDatabase"/>
      </Realm>
      <Host name="localhost"  appBase="/www"
            unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true">
        <!-- SingleSignOn valve, share authentication between web applications
             Documentation at: /docs/config/valve.html -->
        <!--
        <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.authenticator.SingleSignOn" />
        -->
        <!-- Access log processes all example.
             Documentation at: /docs/config/valve.html
             Note: The pattern used is equivalent to using pattern="common" -->
        <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve" directory="logs"
               prefix="localhost_access_log." suffix=".txt"
               pattern="%h %l %u %t &quot;%r&quot; %s %b" />
      </Host>
    </Engine>
  </Service>
</Server>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I mangage to solve this by making a directory in my webpage directory named ROOT and moved all content in to it. Not a perfekt solution but it works.

Answer (score 0):

Just move your files from /www/example to /www and change your DocumentRoot and Directory directives to match.

Comment: I have more then one website in the directory /www so can i change in the config insteed to get the same result?

Comment: I tried it and it did not help at all.